# Windows 8 and 8.1 store stopped working

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-8.1-upgrade

My Windows 8 store stopped working. It works in other accounts but no in mine. I tried using WReset or Windows 8 apps fixer tool from Microsoft, but nothing fixed the issue. I tried everything suggested at this link but still getting the same issue -

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_store/windows-8-store-not-available-right-now-how-to-fix/8d299e60-38a2-4740-b18c-3f81808e2065?msgId=3ca928fa-6c93-409b-9cb6-66087800d61a

I assumed upgrade to Windows 8.1 would fix the issue but I keep getting this error.

Comment: If its an offline account, delete it and create a new one. If its online, see if you can access store through browser..

Comment: @tumchaaditya I can access it through browser, but the browser links for install take me to the app.

Comment: Yeah I know. I just wanted to check if something wrong with your account+store combination

Comment: It is kind of frustrating because I have got support for issue in linux almost immediately. But I have no idea how to solve this issue. Microsoft's solution usually is reinstall or delete account. But the issue occured even after upgrade, so not sure what the problem is here.

Comment: try all steps from here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2013/10/11/what-to-do-if-your-windows-8-modern-app-fails-to-start.aspx